# I need help to select a distinct column values in android query builder

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT  _id AS suggest_intent_data_id, _id,distinct  word as suggest_text_1 
FROM words WHERE (suggest_text_1 like "a%") ORDER BY word LIMIT 10.
```

but it is showing me error near disticnt.

This query works in sqlite manager in firefox:

```sql
SELECT  distinct  word as suggest_text_1 
FROM words WHERE (suggest_text_1 like "a%") ORDER BY word LIMIT 10.
```

but i need the result from first query.

Here is is the code for query builder.

```java
private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() 
{
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, "word as "+SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
    map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "_id");
    //       map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,"meaning as           "+SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2);
    map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "_id AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);

    return map;
}
```

Comment: why the -1.i need help with this.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? If a word exists multiple times, which `_id` should it have?

Answer (score 2):

i solved the problem, i just added **group by** clause to the query and it worked.

```
select _id AS suggest_intent_data_id, _id, word as suggest_text_1 
FROM words WHERE (suggest_text_1 like "a%")  group by word order by word limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perform a select distinct (by row) and not by "row cell"

```
SELECT  distinct id AS suggest_intent_data_id, _id,  word as suggest_text_1 
FROM words WHERE (suggest_text_1 like "a%") 
ORDER BY word LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: a Typo  ... i mean disctint but .. could be the question goal  is not well described

Comment: Yes there a way but plese show your schema and a sample  so i can post   the right  query..

Comment: And you have the same word more time or the single word is present one time only in table

Comment: Show esample of data and result you need

Comment: And you want show the word one time  ... but with which id related ..? because if you have the word  more time you have different id  .. ..which do you want (the firts, the last )?